# Jquery Show/Hide In a .net Datalist

Tags: jquery, .net, datalist

I have a .net Datalist returning news articles what I want to happen is for only the headlines to show and then when you click the headline link the body to show.

This is what I have so far
HTML

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlNewsArticles" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceNewsArticles" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="news">
            <strong><a class="trigger" href="#"><%#Eval("Headline") %></a> </strong><br />
            <div class="newsarticle"><%#Eval("ArticleBody") %></div>
            <br /><br /><br />
        </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Javascript

```
(function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.newsarticle').hide();
            $('a.trigger').click(function () {
                $(this).next("div").slideToggle();


            });
        });
    })(jQuery);
```

The only part that seems to work is the hiding of the .newsarticle divs on load.
Am a complete Noob when it comes to Jquery so any pointers will be gratefully recieved

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `next()` function will return the next element after the `a`. I assume that it is finding the `<br/>`, which doesn't match the `"div"` selector and so nothing is returned.

I would use something like

```
 $(this).parent().siblings("div").slideToggle();
```

That would go to the parent element of the link, `strong` in this case, then find the siblings of the `strong` element that are divs, which would find the one that you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is not quite right. Try -

```
(function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.newsarticle').hide();
            $('a.trigger').click(function () {
                $(this).parents(".news").children(".newsarticle").slideToggle();
            });
        });
    })(jQuery);
```

That should find the parent 'div' of the clicked link that has a `news` class, then find the child item of that din that has the 'newsarticle' class.